# Angular convention for $http / CRUD

Tags: angularjs, crud

What is the Angular convention or standard for using $http to hit an API. I am performing CRUD within my controller and it is getting very fat. Is it common to move this to a factory or is it common to perform these actions in a controller?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using API are pure rest then you can use [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) or [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and if not then better to use `services` for that.Below is the link why we should thin slice controller and have more business logic in services or factory

http://toddmotto.com/rethinking-angular-js-controllers/